# Which preposition to form the superlative in a place

Tags: prépositions, superlatifs

> C'est le bâtiment le plus haut ___ Paris.

Should we use *à* or *de*, or does either work?

Similar question for the following: should we use *en* or *de la* (or should it be just *de*) or either?

> Penses-tu que Paris soit la meilleure ville ___ France ?

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with the superlative construction. It depends on the structure you intend to apply the superlative construction to: *le bâtiment de/dans/à/avant/depuis/... Paris*, *la ville de/en/... France*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer ***de*** which is more idiomatic in both cases:

> C'est le bâtiment le plus haut de Paris.

*Le plus haut de Paris* is a single unit while *le plus haut à Paris* is less coupled. You might say:

> À Paris, c'est le bâtiment le plus haut.

while:

> *De Paris, c'est le bâtiment le plus haut.*

would be much less natural and possibly ambiguous.

Same for the second sentence:

> Penses-tu que Paris soit la meilleure ville de France ?

It still sounds a little odd though as something is missing for it to be complete and idiomatic, like:

> Est-ce que tu penses que Paris est la meilleure ville **de** France **pour** s'amuser / trouver du travail / se déplacer en transport en commun / etc.

Comment: Tout à fait d'accord avec cette réponse, sauf un petit détail: "Penses-tu que Paris soit la meilleure ville de France"  pourrait très bien se dire, même sans précision.

Comment: Wether you want to emphasise the height of the building, you could also use "de tout" : "C'est le bâtiment le plus haut de tout Paris"

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE « Penses-tu » est bien sûr correct mais n'est utilisé que dans la langue soutenue, autant dire rarement, et l'on peut, c'est vrai, dire « la meilleure ville de France » mais je trouve simplement que ce n'est pas souvent utilisé sans préciser quel critère est considéré, contrairement à « meilleure patisserie de France » par exemple, où le critère ne fait pas de doute.

Comment: A propos de juste "penses-tu" ou la totalité de la phrase? Je ne penses pas que "Penses-tu" "Pensez-vous"soit si rare, je (et mon entourage) l’utilisons régulièrement, même à l'oral. Il y a une grande difficulté à établir "ce qui se dit couramment" ou pas, parce que ça dépend vraiment de la zone géographique, du milieu social, et de beaucoup de choses. C'est pour ça que je n'aime pas trop quand la réponse est "ça ne se dit jamais", il faudrait dire: dans mon entourage, jamais on ne l'utilise.

Comment: Il ne faut pas seulement considérer la langue orale, mais aussi la langue écrite. "autant dire rarement" = non. Quand on écrit, en contexte professionnel, c'est cette langue qu'on utilise.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Je n'ai jamais écrit « ça ne se dit jamais », juste que c'était *a little odd* et dans mon commentaire « rarement », pas « jamais ». Je ne base pas seulement cet avis sur mon entourage mais sur les  études de linguistes qui décrivent l'évolution de la langue parlée et la disparition progressive de la postposition du sujet dans certaines formes de questions. Les publications de Claire Blanche-Benveniste sont par exemple très instructives. On ne dit pas « je (et mon entourage) l'utilisons » mais, « moi et mon entourage l'utilisons » ou « je l'utilise ainsi que mon entourage ».

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE et dans un contexte professionnel, on écrira plutôt « Pensez-vous que Paris soit la meilleure ville de France ? ». Le tutoiement est un indice fort qui permet de supposer qu'il s'agit de français oral d'un registre courant ou familier.

Comment: Quand on parle dans des commentaires, on parle d'une façon relaxée, C'est ce qui s'appelle une incise j'ai commencé par dire je et j'ai fait l'incise (et mon entourage), comme quand on parle à l'oral, ce n'est pas la même chose que "je et mon entourage". Même si je fais autant de fautes que n'importe qui, il faudrait me reprendre sur mes fautes plutôt que lorsque je prends une liberté volontaire avec la grammaire.

Comment: Il faut comprendre quand quelqu'un s'exprime de façon "parlé" dans les commentaires, qu'on ne relit pas, quo'n ne peut pas éditer facilement, et dans lesquels il y a une quantité astronomiques de fautes, pas seulement de ma part. Je continuerais à utiliser une façon très relaxée de parler dans les coms, et plus soignée dans les questions que ça plaise ou non. Si tu veux t'amuser à compter le nombre de coquilles que je fais dans les coms, bon courage! Et me donner des leçons sur les adverbes comme si j'apprenais le français, pourquoi pas.

Comment: Je ne vois pas de freins à utiliser "Penses-tu que".

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Je ne reprends que très rarement les erreurs dans les commentaires, et je conviens que c'est assez "mal élevé" de ma part, d'autant plus qu'il m'arrive bien sûr d'en faire aussi. Je ne l'ai fait ici ou ailleurs que pour souligner l'incohérence du discours entre quelqu'un qui déforme mes réponses, qui affirme s'exprimer dans un français soutenu à l'oral mais dont les réponses et commentaires ne reflètent pas une telle maîtrise du français. Par exemple « de façon "parlé**e**" », « je ne vois pas de **frein** à utiliser ».

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE  De toute façon, un modérateur finira certainement par effacer tout nos commentaires si stériles.

Comment: Alors la raison est complètement stupide. Je ne suis pas d'accord avec toi, alors je souligne tes fautes. Si c'est de la cohérence, je ne la vois nulle part, ça s'appelle du mauvais esprit. Si je prétends utiliser telle formule à l'oral, c'est que c'est le cas, donc ça vaut comme témoignage. Je n'ai encore vu personne dire "Je m'exprimer de telle façon" pour se faire plaisir. Bon amusement à essayer de trouver des fautes, pas gratuitement, pour rendre service à l'autre, mais pour te mettre en valeur, c'est une occupation qui doit être passionnante.

Comment: C'est dommage que l'éthique ne soit pas au programme. Bref, je ne préfère pas perdre mon temps avec les personnes qui utilisent ce genre de procédés, comme lorsqu'on est à court d'arguments pour démolir ceux de l'autre. ça joue en ta défaveur... Moi je n'ai rien à me reprocher vis-à-vis d'un modérateur, je parle de l'usage de la langue, pas de gamineries à côté.

Comment: Surtout pour dire des choses aussi absurdes. Avant de donner des leçons aux autres, commence par avoir un usage irréprochable (pas trop le cas). "Je ne vois pas de freins à utiliser" Quelqu'un qui réfléchit, comprend que les freins peuvent être au pluriel Ce n'est pas une expression figée.
"

Comment: Si je voulais des cours de français, mon choix se porterait sur une personne compétente...Parce qu'une personne qui pense que "Penses-tu" est du langage super recherché, on voit le niveau....Bon allez, c'est fini les gamineries. Je ne pensais pas que les gens pouvaient être aussi mesquins ici. On se croirait à la maternelle....

Answer (score -1):

I think both are ok. just like using " 's" and "in" in english.

For your second sentence, It would be between "de" and "en". "de la" is good too.

Comment: Both are grammatically ok, but *de* is preferred to *à* in the first sentence. You'll hear it more and it sounds more correct. (Actually it's just correct, but the other is borderline). Same thing in the second sentence, *de* is the best one, *en* is "alright I guess", and *de la* doesn't sound good correct. You can say "*Le PIB **de la** France*" but with superlatives with countries or cities, "*de*" is the best option by far.

Comment: Les deux n'ont pas du tout le même sens ! The correct grammatical form for a superlative is always "de", and never "à".

Answer (score -3):

> C'est le bâtiment le plus haut ___ Paris

You have to use "de".

**Superlative**: You have the form: **le plus + adjective + de**
Grammatical variants: le/la/les plus.... de/du

Ex:

- Mon papa est l'homme **le plus** fort **du** monde.
- C'est **la plus** belle fille **de l**'univers.

If you write:

> C'est le bâtiment le plus haut, à Paris

Sounds incorrect and weird. Like jlliagre said:

> À Paris, c'est le bâtiment le plus haut.

could be said, but the real superlative form is much better.

Comment: C'est quand même bizarre tous ces downvotes en même temps sur toutes mes questions, subitement! Et toujours sans avoir l'amabilité d'apporter une précision!